# Cannot upload multiple APKs targeting multiple CPU architectures on Google Play Developer Console

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-console

I have built a game in Unity Android.

I want to upload multiple APKs targeting different CPU architectures in Google Play Developer Console.
Targeting 64 bit CPU architecture is compulsory, we cannot publish apps without targeting 64-bit architecture. I have uploaded APK targeting **ARM64** CPU architecture and rolled it out to production successfully.

Now the problem is that I want to add APKs targeting **ARMv7** (32-bit) and **x86** CPU architectures.
For that, I have:

- Created New Release.
- Uploaded APK that targets **ARMv7** with different Version code.
- I have **retained** previous APK that was targeting **ARM64** so that current release will offer 64-bit version for 64-bit devices.

Now when I Proceed to **Review** I am getting errors

> **Error**
> This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement
> The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 8.

> **Fully shadowed APK**
> **Problem**:
> This APK will not be served to any users because it is completely shadowed by one or more APKs with higher version codes.

Here is the **Screesnhot**:

[image]

It is saying that I need to include support for 64-bit architecture. But I have already uploaded APK previously for the same. I cannot upload ARMv7 and x86 versions of the app.

Comment: What is your version code for previous and current apk?

Comment: can you show build setting?

Comment: @SaadAnees, Version Code for **ARM64** is **7**, Version Code for **ARMv7** is **8**. There is no version code conflict. APKs are uploaded successfully in the release, I am getting those errors while Publishing the app (Rolling out the release). Also I don't think there is any Build Setting problem, as I can Publish the app with single APK targeting **ARM64 & ARMv7** both or single APK targeting only **ARM64**. The problem occurs when I try to Publish the app with separate APK targeting **ARMv7**.

Comment: You cannot upload apps targeting x86.

Comment: @SaadAnees, How can I not upload apps targeting **x86**?, Google still supports **x86** with ~328 device models. Also, I am asking about **ARMv7** architecture which is supported by ~15125 device models. Please note that **x86** is different from **ARMv7**. For my problem, I think it's problem with Google as it says I can split and upload multiple APKs for different CPU architectures, but on the other hand, it says I cannot upload "splitted" or single APK that only targets **ARMv7** or architecture other than **ARM64**.

Answer (score 1):

> Starting August 1, 2019, your apps published on Google Play will need to support 64-bit architectures. 64-bit CPUs deliver faster, richer experiences for your users. Adding a 64-bit version of your app provides performance improvements, makes way for future innovation, and sets you up for devices with 64-bit-only hardware.

Source: [Support 64-bit architectures](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit)

If you are using a version of Unity that supports 64-bit Android libraries, you can generate a 64-bit version of your app by adjusting your build settings. You will also need to use the IL2CPP backend as your Scripting Backend (details [here](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2017/12/20/meeting-google-play-requirements-in-the-future/)). To set up your Unity project to build 64-bit architecture, do the following:

1. Go to Build Settings and ensure you are building for Android by
   verifying that the Unity symbol is next to Android under Platform.
2. If the Unity symbol is not next to the Android platform, select
   Android and click Switch Platform.
3. Click Player settings.
4. Player settings in Unity
5. Navigate to Player Settings Panel > Settings for Android > Other
   settings > Configuration
6. Set Scripting Backend to IL2CPP.
7. Select the Target Architecture > ARM64 checkbox.
8. set target architectures in Unity
9. Build as normal!

Comment: I know how to build 64 bit apps using IL2CPP. I have also published 64-bit apps. Until now I was using 64-bit & 32-bit both in single APK, but that was giving a larger APK size, so I decided to split 64-bit & 32-bit separately as it gives smaller APK size and targets devices native to respective CPU architectures. Now the problem is I have published 64-bit APK with Version code 7 successfully. Now I want to add 32-bit APK **(ARMv7)** to Google Play Console so that my app is supported by ~15125 more device models.

Comment: As mentioned in the blow all apps are required to have 64-bit. if you have larger file size you can use .aab file extention

Answer (score 0):

You should provide bigger bundle version code for more enchansed apk.
In this case arm64 Version Code must be 8, and arm-v7 Version Code is 7.

This is because the "device" is looking for the first matching APK with the highest Version Code. And since arm64 cpu support arm-v7, then in your case they will all receive the arm-v7 version, since its Version is higher, ie it hides the assembly for arm 64.